AWS amplify deploy, cannot assume role
I can't deploy the AWS Amplify app with the following error:
2024-09-01T17:25:22.085Z [ERROR]: !!! Unable to assume specified IAM Role. Please ensure the selected IAM Role has sufficient permissions and the Trust Relationship is configured correctly.
2024-09-01T17:25:22.175Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2024-09-01T17:25:22.175Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed

I followed these instructions and gave all the Amplify permissions by creating a new service role and choosing "AWS service. For Use case, select Amplify" as per instructions.
Furthermore, I added the following policy to the role:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "amplify:*",
                "cloudfront:*",
                "logs:*",
                "cloudformation:*",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "lambda:*",
                "cognito-idp:*",
                "cognito-identity:*",
                "appsync:*",
                "dynamodb:*",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

And this is the trust policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "amplify.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}

And I configured the Amplify app to use the role I created.

It just won't work. Just will not work no matter what.
Can someone please kindly give me a hint on how to fix this?
P.S. I'm launching the deploy as root user on AWS.
